# check remotely whether all files are present or not in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I have a below script which iterates all the machine and check in each machine remotely:

- A particular directory is there or not?
- And all 2000 files are present or not in that directory.

Below is the code:

```
for machine in "${MACHINES[@]}"; do
   dircheck=($(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@${machine} [[ ! -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& exit 1 \; ls -t1 "$dir3"))
   if [[ $? != 0 ]] ;then
       echo "Folder $dir3 doesn't exist on $machine" >&2
       exit 1
   fi

    # this is for checking all the 2000 files
    # this check is very slow when it checks all 2000 files
    for el in ${FILES[@]}
    do
        printf -v cmd '%q ' test -e "$dir3/process_${el}.log"
        ssh user@${machine} "$cmd" \
        || { echo "File number $el missing on $machine." >&2;
             exit 1; }
    done
done
```

Now problem is checking all 2000 files takes lot of times so wanted to see if there is any way we can still do the same thing but little bit fast?

**Update:**

So overall my script will be like this:

```
readonly MACHINES=(machineA machineB machineC)
readonly dir3=/some_path
echo $dir3
FILES=({0..1999})

checkFunc() {
  test -d "$dir3" || echo "NODIR"

  local filename successCount=0
  while IFS= read -r filename; do
    test -e "$dir3/process_${filename}.log" && (( ++successCount ))
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$successCount"
}

for machine in "${MACHINES[@]}"; do
    actual=$(
      printf '%s\0' "${FILES[@]}" | \
        ssh "$machine" "$(declare -p dir3; declare -f checkFunc); checkFunc"
    ) || { echo "ERROR: Unable to retrieve remote file count" >&2; exit 1; }

    case $actual in
      (${#FILES[@]}) echo "SUCCESS: Expected, and found, $numberOfActuallyRemoteFiles files" ;;
      (NODIR)        echo "FAILURE: Directory $dir3 does not exist" ;;
      (*)            echo "FAILURE: Out of ${#FILES[@]} files, only $actual exist" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: BTW, `array=( $(...) )` is generally speaking a code smell -- unless you're careful, it's prone to expanding things that look like globs locally, and/or splitting filenames into multiple elements when they contain whitespace. It's almost always more appropriate to do something more like `while IFS= read -r line; do array+=( "$line" ); done < <(...)` instead; *especially* if you can NUL-delimit your stream and thus use `IFS= read -r -d '' line`.

Comment: The SFTP protocol is better suited to accessing remote files than plain ssh. Unfortunately, the OpenSSH `sftp` command-line utility isn't very good for automating. If you know python, perl, etc. then you should consider implementing this in one of those languages, using an SFTP library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating 2,000 separate SSH connections, push the entire loop to the remote side:

```
# shell function which reads a NUL-delimited list of filenames on stdin
# and returns the number of them that actually exist on stdout, or "NODIR"
checkFunc() {
  test -d "$dir3" || { echo "NODIR"; return; }

  local filename successCount=0
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    test -e "$dir3/process_${filename}.log" && (( ++successCount ))
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$successCount"
}

actual=$(
  printf '%s\0' "${FILES[@]}" | \
    ssh "$machine" "$(declare -p dir3; declare -f checkFunc); checkFunc"
) || { echo "ERROR: Unable to retrieve remote file count" >&2; exit 1; }

case $actual in
  (${#FILES[@]}) echo "SUCCESS: Expected, and found, $numberOfActuallyRemoteFiles files" ;;
  (NODIR)        echo "FAILURE: Directory $dir3 does not exist" ;;
  (*)            echo "FAILURE: Out of ${#FILES[@]} files, only $actual exist" ;;
esac
```

Note that `declare -p dir3` and `declare -f checkFunc` emit strings which, when executed by bash, will define the `dir3` variable or the `checkFunc` function, respectively.

Comment: In your example where does $host is coming from?

Comment: @john, that's your responsibility to provide. I suppose it would be `$machine` if using the original variable naming convention. You still need a loop with one SSH call per machine -- we need to connect to each one in turn, after all -- but the point is that we shouldn't be calling ssh *once per file per machine*.

Comment: got it.. so I updated my question with the full script along with the loop of iterating all the machines. Does this look right in the way we are having one ssh call per machine or there is anything wrong?

Comment: So I ran this script but it always print `"FAILURE: Out of 2000 files, only 0 exist"` and I checked files are present remotely in that folder. Any thoughts what could be wrong? Updated my question with full script I am using. I believe problem lies in `checkFunc` method or the way we are calling `checkFunc` but not able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Put `set -x;` at the beginning of the remote command, so, making it `ssh "$machine" "set -x; $(declare -p dir3; declare -f checkFunc); checkFunc"` -- that way we'll get a log of execution so you can see the individual `test` executions run.

Comment: One thing I did notice on a reread is that I was NUL-delimiting the list, but reading it in a manner suitable for newline-delimiting. I changed `checkFunc` to expect NUL-delimited input -- see if that helps.

Comment: Yes that fixes the problem. When I was testing it out for the case in which directory doesn't exist, then it should print `"FAILURE: Directory $dir3 does not exist"` instead it was printing `FAILURE: Out of 2000 files, only NODIR 0 exist`. Any idea why?

Comment: Oops -- that should be `|| { echo "NODIR"; return; }`. Amended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162938/discussion-between-john-and-charles-duffy).